# Something wrong with my weight paint or mesh

Tags: modeling, weight-painting

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, the bones move faster than the mesh and the mesh gets deformed, it's like part of the mesh gets left behind, this also happens on some one of the other bones but I've including a screenshot for one of them, I've weight painted characters like this before so I really don't know what's happening this time.[image]

The majority of the other bones work fine, can someone help me solve this?

Comment: some other bones must influence these parts, you need to correct this in Weight Paint mode or with the Assign and Remove buttons under the Vertex Groups list, or the Remove From All Groups function on the right of this Vertex Groups list

Comment: Seems like there is some little vertices wasn't assign to the bones correctly. So those vertices drag the hand behind the bone.